# Access table.id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have a webpage, which has a number of [ASP.NET tables](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_table.asp).

The tables are defined on the server as follows (id is unique for every table):

```
dim tblOutput as table
tblOutput.ID = id
```

I am trying to loop through all the tables on the webpage using JavaScript on the client as follows:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); 
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    var res2 = trs[i].attributes("id")
    alert(res2[i].id)
}
```

The alert always prints 'undefined'.  I have debugged using firefox and id is always empty ("").  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you already assign the id to res2.. so alert(res2) wouldn't give you the id?

Comment: `attributes` is not a function. You can get the id by writing `trs[i].id`

Comment: if you are using jquery (as in your tag) - `$('table').each(function() { console.log(this.id); });`

Comment: Make sure you don't invent properties that don't even exist before asking a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res2 = trs[i].attributes("id")
alert(res2[i].id)
```

You assign a single string to res2 and then you use res2 like it's an array in your alert.  You then try and get the id from a string?  Not sure what you're trying to do there...  Additionally, `attributes` is not a function, you can access the id with `.id`.

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; ++i) {
    var id = tables[i].id;
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: I already found this solution, but thanks anyway.  I will accept.